# Processed date must be within open periods in Oracle Incentive Compensation

Tags: oracle-apps

We are facing an error on the screen in the compensation manager responsibilty in Manage Transacations --> Create

When we try to create a new transaction, we get the error "Processed date must be within open periods."

Though we have setup the primary ledger the accounting calculator as well as the open periods  and the date being selected in the Processed Date is within the open period specified but still we are facing this error
Also, how will be know that our Operating Unit is attached to that particular ledger.
If we can confirm that the OU selected is associated to the ledger for which we have defined the open period. Can this be the reason or there is some other reason. Kindly help.
[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone. I was missing the general parameter setup. 
Incentive Compensation Administrator 
Configuration Workbench > Application Parameters > Go To Task > Setup General Parameters
And Yes after that I have to open the compensation periods as mentioned by vijay bhamidipati

Answer (score 1):

Please check to see if compensation periods are open in OIC.

navigation:

Compensation Manager> Setup>Maintain Compensation Periods.

Comment: Yes thank you for that. Actually I was missing the General Parameters setup. Finally it is fixed.